# Converting a list of ints separated by spaces into list of ints with commas?

Tags: python, list, int

Say I have the list:

```
ship_sizes = ['1 1 2 1 1']
```

How do I make it into `[1, 1, 2, 1, 1]` ?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the following:

```
In [11]: map(int, ship_sizes[0].split())
Out[11]: [1, 1, 2, 1, 1]
```

The index `0` allows you to access the string `'1 1 2 1 1'`. The `split()` function then converts this string into `['1', '1', '2', '1', '1']`, a list of strings. Finally, using `map` with the function `int` converts each string in the list into an integer.

Comment: This is me using the console! Have you used the console before? If not, ignore the `In[11]:` and `Out[11]:` - they are not part of the code

Comment: After I put in map(int, ship_sizes[0].split()), I get 
<map object at 0x7f6c42951588>
but no output?

Comment: you need ``list(map(...))`` to explicitly convert it to a list.

Answer (score 2):

Since your first list simply contains one single element which is a string, you can use the split() function.

```
splitShips = ship_sizes[0].split()

newShips = [int(ship) for ship in splitShips]
```

Comment: Getting the error "TypeError: Can't convert 'list' object to str implicitly" after trying to input the first function

Comment: What python version are you using? The code works on Python 2.7.9

Comment: Also, `split()` with no arguments splits on whitespace.  `'1      2 3    \n'.split()` returns `['1', '2', '3']`.

Comment: @MSeifert - you are right, my mistake. I edited the code.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski, true, edited the code again. Thanks

Comment: Ok, just ran it on Python 3.4. The example should work.

Answer (score 1):

the following code should also work.

```
ship_sizes = ['1 1 2 1 1']
strVariable = ship_sizes[0].split(' ')
resultArray = []

i = 0
for i in range(len(strVariable)):
    resultArray.append(int(strVariable[i]))

print(resultArray)
```